# Force iOS to violate constraints?

Tags: objective-c, storyboard, nslayoutconstraint

I'm working with a storyboard I didn't draft. I've had problems presenting a UIDocumentInteractionController. On one of the View Controllers I changed the constraint style to Over Current Context and that fixed it. On the other one, this did nothing and I run into a constraint violation crash.

Is there a way to force the constraint violation so I can present my UIDocumentInteractionController modally?

Comment: please fix your problem instead of hack around it

Comment: I'm investigating that. My question still stands.